# How to retrieve last object in sorted Binding list (.Net, LINQ)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, bindinglist

I have a `BindingList` with `Comment` objects inside. `Comment` contains `DateTime` and `string`

I need to order list by date (latest date last) and get `string` without making copies of `BindingList` nor affecting it's order.

How can such be accomplished?

Comment: Should point out that I have accomplished this by coping BindingList, sorting it. Then selecting last element.

Comment: Do you want a single string, or all of the strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve all of the strings, you can use:

```
IEnumerable<string> theStringsInOrder = theBindingList.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date).Select(c => c.TheString);
```

For the string associated with the "max" date:

```
string latestString = theBindingList.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date).First().TheString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string s = BindingList .comment.OrderByDescending(o=> o.Date).select(o=> o.string).FirstOrDefault();
```